# How to create form finisher in TYPO3 v11?

Tags: php, typo3

I am trying to add a finisher for EXT:form to my TYPO3. I didn't find an example that is up to date. Most are about TYPO3 v8.

I using this "explanation" https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/main/en-us/I/Concepts/Finishers/Index.html#write-a-custom-finisher

This is my state:

/Configuration/Finishers/Smtp.yaml

```
  TYPO3:
    CMS:
      Form:
        prototypes:
          standard:
            finishersDefinition:
              SmtpFinisher:
                implementationClassName: 'Vendor\personal\Domain\Finishers\SmtpFinisher'
                options:
                    yourCustomOption: 'Ralf'
```

/Classes/Domain/Finishers/SmtpFinisher.php

```
  <?php declare(strict_types=1);

  namespace VENDOR\personal\Domain\Finishers;

  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
  use TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Finishers\AbstractFinisher;


  final class SmtpFinisher extends AbstractFinisher
  {

    protected $shortFinisherIdentifier = 'smtp';

    public function executeInternal() : void{
      $senderOptoins = $this->parseOptions("sender");
      $mailer = new PHPMailer();

      $mailer->isSMTP();
      $mailer->SMTPAuth =true;
      $mailer->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;

      $mailer->Port = $senderOptoins["smtpPort"];
      $mailer->Host = $senderOptoins["smtpServer"];

      $mailer->Username = $senderOptoins["username"];
      $mailer->Password = $senderOptoins["password"];

      $mailer->setFrom($senderOptoins["senderAddress"]) ;


      foreach($this->parseOptions("recipents") as $recipent){
        $mailer->addAddress($recipent);
      }

      $mailer->isHTML();
      $mailer->Subject = "Hello, World!";
      $mailer->Body = "Hi Test Email";
      $mailer->AltBody = "Hi Test Email";

      $mailer->Send();
    }
  }

  ?>
```

/ext_localconf.php

```
  if (\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::isLoaded('form')) {
      \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTypoScriptSetup(trim('
          module.tx_form {
              settings {
                  yamlConfigurations {
                      311 = EXT:personal/Configuration/Finishers/Smtp.yaml
                  }
              }
          }
          plugin.tx_form {
              settings {
                  yamlConfigurations {                      
                      311 = EXT:personal/Configuration/Finishers/Smtp.yaml
                  }
              }
          }
      '));
  }
```

But I am still not seeing my finisher:

[image]

Furthermore I don't know how I can include php libraries. How do I "ship" them to my extension/TYPO3?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't configure mailing in TYPO3 generally to use your SMTP server?

Comment: Yes. I use the TYPO3 for different domains. So I need several different SMTPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include your new finisher to the Option-List. See here:

https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/11.5/en-us/I/Concepts/Finishers/Index.html#add-finisher-to-backend-ui

Secondly:

For including external custom PHP libraries, you can use a vendor folder in your extension. The PHP libraries should be classes with namespace.

If you install the extension via composer you also have to include the PSR4 in the composer.json of the extension. Then the class names are available after an install.

And in the finisher you set a constructor which includes the classes (for this a service.yaml must exist in the extension).

Example:

```
- your_extension_key
   - Classes
      - Finishers
        - YourMailFinisher.php
   - Configuration
      - service.yaml
   - Vendor
      - YourPhpLibrary.php
   - composer.json
```

service.yaml

```
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

  YourVendor\YourExtensionKey\:
    resource: '../Classes/*'

  YourVendor\YourExtensionKey\Finisher\YourMailFinisher:
    public: true
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "yourVendor/your-extension-key",
    "type": "typo3-cms-extension",
    "description": "...",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "YOU",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "require": {
        "typo3/cms-core": "^11.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "typo3/testing-framework": "^6.9.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "YourVendor\\YourExtensionKey\\": "Classes"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "Vendor"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {},
    "replace": {
        "typo3-ter/your-extension-key": "self.version"
    },
    "extra": {
        "typo3/cms": {
            "extension-key": "your_extension_key"
        }
    }
}
```

YourMailFinisher.php

```
<?php
namespace YourVendor\YourExtensionKey\Finishers;

use TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Finishers\AbstractFinisher;

class YourMailFinisher extends AbstractFinisher
{
   protected $yourLibrary;

   public function __construct(\Vendor\PhpLibrary $yourLibrary)
   {
       $this->yourLibrary = $yourLibrary;
   }

   protected function executeInternal()
   {
      // your code - for use Library: $this->yourLibrary->yourFunction()
   }
}
```

Not tested, is just a quick code snippet.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. When I try to add the finisher to the backend UI, I get the following error: `mixins.formElementMixins.BaseCollectionEditorsMixin does not exist within the configuration.`
Do you have any hints? I think it is outdated, but I can't find an update.
I already tried it with this line `<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:Form/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript">` in the `setup.typoscript`
Best Regards
peni4142

Comment: Hi. Okay, the link from above was a little bit outdated (has the old __inheritances, witch not exist anymore). thats the correct link for TYPO3 v11.5

https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/11.5/en-us/I/Concepts/Finishers/Index.html#add-finisher-to-backend-ui

Comment: Ok, I still have some trouble. I think the problem is too complex to discuss here in a thread only so I created a repo at GitHub (https://github.com/peni4142/smtp_finisher) I planned that anyway. The actual error is: " #1278450972 TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Reflection\Exception\UnknownClassException" The error appears when I try to load the form with the finisher.
Maybe you want to have a look at the repo?
Thank you, for your time.

Comment: I have open an issues with my comment

Comment: Hi Kay, thank you for your time. That is really nice! I will have a closer look on Wednesday. I think I can‘t make it sooner. Dear Peer

Comment: I have not reached my goal yet, but I am getting close to that, and all questions are answered.
I think I can get there by my own
Thank you really much!

Comment: Hi Kay,
I did some progress. The finisher settings are connected to the form input. There are still some changes I would like to make. Being able to add pictures would be nice. And I want that the HTML Body allows HTML tags. It would be nice if the Recipient could be a list of values.
Do I have to design such templates on my own? Do you know where to find documentation for that?

Comment: Hi see my pull request for HTML-Tags for Body and recipients as List.

Comment: For an image configuration in the finisher I have no idea at the moment either. I have never needed such a case so far. Images are always set manually in the HTML template (we use Fluid-Standalone).

Comment: Hi Kay I want to say again: Thank you!
There are still some issues, but nothing that will make a breaking change on an update (So far I have planned it yet). So now I can use it for my needs and beautify it later.

Comment: Hi Kay,
I still have a problem, and I don't know why. Maybe you can help me. I have described my struggle here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76076187/overrideable-email-array-in-a-typo3-form-finisher