# Overrideable Email Array in a TYPO3 Form Finisher

Tags: typo3, typo3-12.x

I try to create a smtp_finisher. For that, I need an overrideable email array.

My actual result looks like that:

[image: images shows that shows the two issues that will be described]

There are two issues. For some reason, the additional pair is always at the bottom, which does not fit the logic. When my PHP code is called, it looks like it is its own array, and in the view, it does not fit into the array.
The second thing is that the stored data aren't shown, even not the fields.

I think that is the relevant snippets you need to find the error:

```
                        200:
                          identifier: 'notifying'
                          templateName: Inspector-PropertyGridEditor
                          label: 'Notifying'
                          propertyPath: 'options.notifying'
                          propertyValidators:
                            10: 'NotEmpty'
                          fieldExplanationText: formEditor.elements.Form.finisher.EmailToReceiver.editor.recipients.fieldExplanationText
                          isSortable: true
                          enableAddRow: true
                          enableDeleteRow: true
                          useLabelAsFallbackValue: false
                          gridColumns:
                            - name: value
                              title: formEditor.elements.Form.finisher.EmailToSender.editor.recipients.gridColumns.value.title
                            - name: label
                              title: formEditor.elements.Form.finisher.EmailToSender.editor.recipients.gridColumns.label.title
```

```
                  notifying:
                    title: Notifying List
                    type: array
                    section: true
                    sectionItemKey: email
                    sectionItemValue: name
                    el:
                      _arrayContainer:
                        type: array
                        title: arrayContainer Title
                        el:
                          email:
                            TCEforms:
                              label: Email
                              config:
                                type: input
                                eval: 'required,email'
                          name:
                            TCEforms:
                              label: Name
                              config:
                                type: input
```

I run the code on TYPO3 12.3.0 instance with a PHP of 8.1.16.

You can find the whole extension here:
https://github.com/peni4142/smtp_finisher

and the configuration file I have the snippets from can be found here:
https://github.com/peni4142/smtp_finisher/blob/main/Configuration/Finishers/Smtp.yaml

#Update:

When I have no element in the array, I get the following error:

[image: Shows an TypeError "Cannot access offset of type string on string"]

I also forgot to mention that I used the code from the form extension as an example.

And it seems that the code works on version 11.5.21 of TYPO3 fine.

Thank you for your time.

peni4142